# gnome weather forecast information is currently unavailable

Tags: gnome, weather

My Gnome weather forecast is unavailable (I use Ubuntu 20.10).

The error is

> Failed to get Yr.no forecast data: 404 Not Found.

I found [a solution](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/libgweather/-/issues/82) to upgrade libgweather from 3.36.1 to 3.36.2 but in Ubuntu repository this package is not available.

This package available in Fedora and Arch Linux.

How can I get this package on Ubuntu?

Comment: You will have to file this as a bug since the 3.36.2 is not available in any of the Ubuntu releases at this time.  `ubuntu-bug libgweather`

Answer (score 2):

Since I upgraded Ubuntu from 20.10 to 21.04, weather forecast works well.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Flatpak:

```
flatpak install flathub org.gnome.Weather
```

https://flathub.org/apps/details/org.gnome.Weather